# Files lost after copying from Kubuntu to NTFS external HDD

Tags: kubuntu

I have copied and paste files form my Samsung mobile phone to an external NTFS HDD. Both connected to my Kubuntu 20.04.1 LTS OS. I am sure that I copied them. After a week I switched on my external HDD and I tried to access the files to the external HDD and were all lost. I searched everywhere both in my Kubuntu laptop and the external HDD, the files are nowhere. Any ideas what could be wrong? Any package to fix this for future copy-paste files?

Comment: You have not clearly describe the process of copying your data, or what troubleshooting you have done. Maybe a cable was loose. Maybe you disconnected the phone or disk too soon. Lots of possible maybes.

Comment: Ok, So I connected the mobile phone to the USB of the laptop and the external HDD to another USB. I copied and pasted the files from the mobile's folder to a folder of the the external HDD. I waited for the operation to finish and I safely removed the external HDD and then the mobile phone. Then i unplugged the HDD's  USB and a switched off the external HDD. I haven't faced such a files lost ever again...

Comment: You should still have the original files on your phone since you copied, not moved.

Comment: I have deleted them after the copy. But this does not work. If I copy files in the future I cannot face again such situations..

Comment: Smells like a possible sync issue, which occurs when the files are still being written to the external device when disconnected. My habit is to wait for the notification that it's safe to unplug, then un-plug, the promptly re-plug immediately to verify that the files copied properly...because I've been bitten by sync before.